# Get response headers object in redux with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, github, redux

Using redux in React.js I get the most starred repositories in the last 30 days, now I wanna use the pagination that github api provides but to do so I have to use the headers in the response, how can I do that, how can I change my code to get the headers from the response, this is the function that gets the response:

```
import getDate from './getDate';

export function fetchRepos() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: "FETCH_REPOS_REQUEST",
    });

    return fetch(
      "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>" + 
      getDate() + 
      "&sort=stars&order=desc",
    )
    .then(response => response.json().then(body => ({response, body})))
    .then(({response, body}) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_REPOS_FAILURE",
          error: body.error,
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_REPOS_SUCCESS",
          repos: body.items,
        });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I like to assemble a response object that includes the headers as an object for fetch calls like so:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then(res => (res.headers.get('content-type').includes('json') ? res.json() : res.text())
 .then(data => ({
  headers: [...res.headers].reduce((acc, header) => {
   return {...acc, [header[0]]: header[1]};
  }, {}),
  status: res.status,
  data: data,
 }))
 .then(response => console.log(response)));
```

in your case you could then simply get the headers with `response.headers` in the last `.then()`.

but technically you can access the headers with `res.headers.get('<header.name>')`.